# Can't get Route angular

Tags: angularjs, http, templates, get, routes

I can't open the route "/d"  but "/" is working. What could be the problem? I tried different things but id did not find a solution.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'OrdersController',
        templateUrl: 'views/lp.html'

})
   .when('/d',{
            controller:'OrdersController',
            templateUrl: 'views/order_detail.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

Server side code looks like this. Maybe they don't like each other ;)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/client'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

Order = require('./models/order.js');

//Connect to Mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/groundlevel');
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Please use /api/order');
});

app.get('/api/orders', function (req, res) {
    Order.getOrders(function (err, orders) {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(orders);
    })
});

app.get('/api/orders/:_id',function (req, res) {
    Order.getOrderById(req.params._id, function (err, order) {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(order);
})
});


app.post('/api/orders', function (req, res) {
    var order = req.body;
    Order.addOrder(order, function (err, order) {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(order);
    })
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Running on Port 3000...');
```

Comment: do you have error in your console ?

Comment: Only get Cannot GET /d

Comment: do you have also server side ? maybe your server takes priority to handle the "/d" route. So you need to let your server handle just "/" your home route

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: answered your question

Comment: thanks, your answer is so obvious ;)

Comment: so does it usefull :D

Answer (score 1):

To let your client side application handle the routing. In your server side do the following

```
var path= require('path');
// All other routes should redirect to the index.html
app.route('/*')
  .get((req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/client/index.html'));
});
```