# Unable to remove !# from angular routes while using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-routing

I am using AngularJS in my MVC application. I am facing the very common routing issue where `!#` appears in the URLs. I have looked out for solution and found this solution almost in every accepted answer which fails miserably in my case.
I have used this line of code inside my routing:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

This line doesn't change anything. I tried this one as well:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

but no luck.
Also, I used this tag inside my `<head>` tag:

```
<base href="/">
```

This line doesn't change anything as well.

My routing code and navigation code is given below:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "payment/MakePayment",
            controller: "paymentController"
        })
        .when("/SearchPayment", {
            templateUrl: "payment/SearchPayment",
            controller: "paymentController"
        })
        .when("/Flush", {
            templateUrl: "payment/InvalidateCacheForIndexAction",
            controller: "paymentController"
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
});
```

Navigation code-

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/">Make Payment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SearchPayment">Search Payment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Flush">Flush</a></li>                    
        </ul>
    </div>
```

When site is launched I see `http://localhost:56810/` in browser. When I click on `Search Payment` link the URL in browser reads `http://localhost:56810/#!#SearchPayment`. Same thing happens for `Flush` as well. Also the navigation doesn't take place. That means the change in URLs doesn't get handled by given routeProvider routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('');
```

and remove `#`

```
<li><a href="SearchPayment">Search Payment</a></li>
<li><a href="Flush">Flush</a></li>
```

OR

Just use following so that you dont have to configure your server side for only handling `"/"`

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('');
```

and remove `#`

```
<li><a href="SearchPayment">Search Payment</a></li>
<li><a href="Flush">Flush</a></li>
```

Comment: I did it. Now I don't see !# in the URL when I click on SearchPayment. However the URL which is displayed in the browser reads "http://localhost:56810/SearchPayment" and I get an error "404 Not Found". The templateUrl given for this link in the routeProvider is "payment/SearchPayment". Why is it not getting handled by routeProvider? Am I missing something?

Comment: It gives 404 because your server side handles the routing so Change your server side routing to just handle the "/" route.  In NodeJs see my other answer for this . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42046583/cant-get-route-angular/42046776#42046776

Comment: Updated my answer for both case

Comment: I tried OR part of your answer but the URL still reads: "http://localhost:56810/#!#SearchPayment"

Comment: try to manually go to "localhost:56810/#/SearchPayment check if it works

Comment: Yes it does. Whats wrong with my routing code then?

Comment: change href="SearchPayment"